# Two endpoints for the same resource in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, endpoints

I want to create two endpoints `/comments/` and `/comments/requests/` or something to that effect. The first shows your comments, and the second shows your pending comments (Comments that people sent you that you need to approve).  They both work with a comments model. How could I achieve this in Django Rest Framework?

Right now, my view is

```
class CommentsListview(APIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        comments, _, _, = Comments.get_comment_users(request.user)
        comments_serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response({'comments': comments_serializer.data})

    def requests(sel,f request, format=None):
        _, requests, _ = Comments.get_comment_users(request.user)
        requests_serializer = CommentSerializer(requests, many=True)
        return Response({'requests': requests_serializer.data})
```

I'd like to allow a user to go to `localhost:8000/comments/` to view their comments and `localhost:8000/comments/requests/` to view their pending comment requests. Since I haven't been able to figure this out, the only other sollution would be to require the user to switch the behavior of the endpoint using a parameter as a flag `/comments/?requests=True` but that just seems sloppy.

Comment: Just make a new view with slightly different query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use list_route decorator and genericviewset

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route

class CommentsListview(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        comments, _, _, = Comments.get_comment_users(request.user)
        comments_serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response({'comments': comments_serializer.data})

    @list_route()
    def requests(sel,f request, format=None):
        _, requests, _ = Comments.get_comment_users(request.user)
        requests_serializer = CommentSerializer(requests, many=True)
        return Response({'requests': requests_serializer.data})
```

- `/comments/` will call `list` method
- `/comments/requests/` will call `requests` method

also look at [GenericViews](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) and [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) docs it might be helpfull

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That works perfectly. Also, there needs to be a change in `urls.py` instead of using `CommentsListview.as_view` you need to use `CommentsListview.as_view({'get': 'list'})` and `CommentsListview.as_view({'get': 'request'})`

Comment: please check out [router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) docs, with viewsets it's simpler to use DRF routers